# What is the proper way of referencing journals, as opposed to papers within journals?

Tags: citations, journals

I am wondering how to reference a journal (not a paper published in that journal, nor even an edition of that journal). Ought I to give a formal citation or is it enough to name that journal in the text?

The specific example which caused my confusion is the [Archive of Formal Proofs](https://www.isa-afp.org/) (AFP) which is a repository of proofs in Isabelle along with papers describing them. It is not exactly a journal itself, I suppose, but I think it is similar enough that I have generalised this question to ask about 'journals' (it describes itself as 'organized in the way of a scientific journal').

Another option I suppose would be to cite a paper written by the developers of the AFP about the technology used in the AFP, or the organisation of the AFP.

Comment: How much harder is it to give a "citation" than a "mention"?

Comment: It goes in the bibliography if it's a citation. But I guess my question is not so much 'do I need to bother?' as 'what is the standard/correct way to do this?'.

Comment: @IIM, perhaps you should revise your question to literally ask "how to do this", rather than "should/must one do this"...

Comment: I think you need to present a much more clear case of what exactly it is you are stating that you are wondering whether you need to cite or not. I can certainly think of (rare) cases where no citation is warranted, and I'm guessing yours is not one of those, but it's not really clear what you intend to say.

Comment: @Bryan_Krause I did give a specific example but do you mean that I should not generalise beyond this example? I am interested in the general case of 'journals' as a class also, but perhaps that class is not well-defined, or that question should be asked separately.

Comment: @IIM I don't understand what you want to say. You gave an example of "Archive of Formal Proofs" but no example about how you intend to refer to it.

Comment: @Bryan_Krause When I said 'name it' I meant literally name it i.e. to say the Archive of Formal Proofs as one might say the United Nations or Amazon Web Services. I mean, that is probably not specific or formal enough and I think the currently accepted answer is right to say that it should be treated as formally as possible and given a citation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably best that it goes in the bibliography, which should represent a full accounting of the resources you draw on. It is an obvious place to put the URL of the web site.

In general, it is better to be a bit formal in such things than informal, whether you literally *need* to cite it or not.

Comment: Yes, a certain riff is "be honest"...